# SQL error only occurs in PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm at odds. My SQL query will only send via PhpMyAdmin. If I attempt to send this specific query via PHP, I get an error. When I copy that exact query into PhpMyAdmin, it goes through without a problem.

```
INSERT INTO posts (id, content, poster, timestamp, tags) VALUES ('12056242', 'OMG I just got a #toyota', 'Clunker5', '09/12/14 08:43:36', 'toyota');INSERT INTO `tags` (tag, posts) VALUES ('toyota', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE posts=posts+1; UPDATE `tags` SET posts=posts+1 WHERE tag IN ('toyota');
```

This is the PHP code relevant to the issue

```
//Ups one post for all tags entered by the user
    if(!empty($tags)){
        $tags1 = explode(",", $tags);
        $tags_submit = join("','", $tags1);
        $tags_insert = join("', 1), ('", $tags1);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (id, content, poster, timestamp, tags) VALUES ('$d', '$b', '".$_SESSION['username']."', '$c', '$tags');"
                . "INSERT INTO `tags` (tag, posts) VALUES ('".$tags_insert."', 1)
                        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE posts=posts+1;
                        UPDATE `tags` SET posts=posts+1 WHERE tag IN ('".$tags_submit."');";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }else{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (id, content, poster, timestamp, tags) VALUES ('$d', '$b', '".$_SESSION['username']."', '$c', '$tags');";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
    $error = mysql_error();
   if($result){
       echo "1";
   }else{
       echo error($sql, $error, "Tags: ".$tags, "Post: ".$b, "ID: ".$d);
   }
```

The error is

```
SQL Response: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `tags` (tag, posts) VALUES ('toyota', 1), ('ohmygoodness', 1) ' at line 1.
```

EDIT: Now that I know that I cannot do a multi-query, how can i do this query?

```
INSERT INTO `tags` (tag, posts) VALUES ('".$tags_insert."', 1)
                        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE posts=posts+1;
                        UPDATE `tags` SET posts=posts+1 WHERE tag IN ('".$tags_submit."');
```

Comment: What error do you get? Are you checking mysql_error()? Did you make sure your query is correct after the variables are interpolated?

Comment: 3rd similar question today.

Comment: `INSERT INTO tags (tag, posts) VALUES ('toyota', 1), ('ohmygoodness', 1)` - I've never seen a `VALUES` clause like that, how would that even work?

Comment: If you want to insert multiple rows at one time, you do it like so,

INSERT INTO `table` (`var1`, `var2`) VALUES (`row1_1`, `row1_2`), (`row2_1`, `row2_2`)

Try it, it works

Comment: That query is valid, the problem is you're feeding multiple queries, take the advice of Bill, just query each queries in separate invocations of mysql_query, well you shouldn't use mysql_* anyway, why not use the mysqli_. much much better api or PDO

Comment: @Ghost, thanks. I'll start converting my code to MySQLi

Comment: @WhatTheFruit and important reminder, better to use prepared statements on top of that mysqli, so that you will not be vulnerable to sql injections, migrating in mysqli and still concatenating user input in your queries will be useless, [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to do multiple statements in one invocation of that API function, but `mysql_query()` doesn't support multi-query.

You shouldn't use multi-query anyway. You might expose yourself to a whole class of [SQL injection vulnerabilties](http://xkcd.com/327).

You should execute each SQL statement individually, in separate invocations of `mysql_query()`.

Also, the comment from @JohnConde is appropriate: you should *always* check the return value from `mysql_query()` because it returns **false** if there's an error. If that happens, log or report `mysql_error()` to find out more about what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

From [the `mysql_query` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> Multiple queries are not supported.

So, you can't send multiple statements delimited by `;`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today, I had 2 great answers. Every time you have a SQL statement you need to use mysql_query; this is a better clarification for example, if you had

```
 "INSERT INTO query";
 "INSERT INTO 2nd query";
 mysql_query(process both query "INSERT INTO query";
 this isn't going to work, it'll only work in phpmyadmin or 
 in straight mysql command line sql. not in a php script.

 you'll need to:

 "INSERT INTO query";
 mysql_query(process one query); //you should also use mysql_error() to see the response
 "INSERT INTO 2nd query";
 mysql_query(process 2nd query);
```

it will need to be formed in 2 separate mysql query. its a security feature on the php side to prevent sql injections. for whatever reason that's what it is.